# Poisson fixed and random effect

Tags: r, random-effects-model, poisson-regression

I have claim frequency panel data for five years consisting of age, CC, make of car, age and gender of insured person and geographical area. I have run a Poisson regression to model the claim frequency in R. Now I want to test for a Poisson fixed and random effect. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice presentation on fixed and random effect analysis in R. It's not for Poisson data, but you may still find it helpful: http://www.princeton.edu/~otorres/Panel101R.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is too late now, but you can consider pglm package from Yves Croisant.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pglm/pglm.pdf

This package does poisson and negbin with fixed and random effects.